# Testing A Library That Uses The Web Audio API With Mocha & Chai

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, web-audio-api, jsdom

I am building a library which uses the web audio api(ToneJS to be more specific).

I have tried using *jsdom, mocha-jsdom* with no success.

I get this error -

```
node_modules/tone/build/Tone.js:3869
                this.input = this.output = this._gainNode = this.context.createGain();
```

Which makes sense and tells me that i need to use an environment with a context.

I'm not even sure how i should setup the tests for my [project](https://github.com/Seanitzel/note-art).

***How should i setup a test environment correctly for my project?***

Comment: Have you tried to set `global.TONE_SILENCE_VERSION_LOGGING` option as suggested by this [issue](https://github.com/Tonejs/Tone.js/issues/439) ?

Comment: Yep, doesn't help and also not my issue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to not use Tone.js at all in your unit tests. Tone.js only works in the browser as it requires the Web Audio API. Instead you could use a spy/mock/stub of Tone.js which just makes sure that you use Tone as intended.

If you for example want to write a test for the [AudioManager](https://github.com/Seanitzel/Note-Art/blob/master/src/models/AudioManager.js) you could create a stripped down mock of Tone.js which just provides what you need.

```
const FakeTone = {
    Players: function () { },
    context: { resume () { } }
};
```

Next I would recommend to rewrite the AudioManager in a way that it accepts Tone as a constructor argument instead of importing it. This will make testing a lot easier. Instead of ...

```
import Tone from 'tone';

export class AudioManager {

    // ...

    generatePlayers () {
        return new Tone.Players()
    }

    // ...

}
```

... it would then be ...

```
export class AudioManager {

    constructor (Tone) {
        this.Tone = Tone;
    }

    // ...

    generatePlayers () {
        return new this.Tone.Players();
    }

    // ...

}
```

... which looks a bit ugly at first, but you hopefully get used to it after a while. :-)

This will allow you to test the AudioManager with the FakeTone object.

```
const audioManager = new AudioManager(FakeTone);

expect(audioManager.generatePlayers()).to.be.an.instanceOf(FakeTone.Players);
```

You could also use something like [Sinon.JS](https://sinonjs.org) to write more advanced tests.

Comment: Actually that is exactly how i solved it, i didnt update the question.
Answer accepted :)