# How to fix "TypeError: Cannot read property 'createGain' of null" while testing Tonejs in Jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, web-audio-api

I'm trying to test react components which use Tonejs. It fails as I try to create Synth object.

I have already tried specifying options (envelopes etc), nothing helped. 
Is it a problem with webaudioAPI not being available in nodejs?

```
it('create Synth', () => {
  const synth = new Tone.Synth().toMaster();
});
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createGain' of null
   at new createGain (node_modules/tone/build/webpack:/Tone/Tone/core/Gain.js:23:1)
   at new t.Volume (node_modules/tone/build/webpack:/Tone/Tone/component/Volume.js:25:1)
   at t.Synth.t.Instrument [as constructor] (node_modules/tone/build/webpack:/Tone/Tone/instrument/Instrument.js:22:1)
   at t.Synth.call [as constructor] (node_modules/tone/build/webpack:/Tone/Tone/instrument/Monophonic.js:18:1)
   at new call (node_modules/tone/build/webpack:/Tone/Tone/instrument/Synth.js:23:1)
   at Object.<anonymous>.it (src/App.test.tsx:15:17)
```

Comment: so your component is using `Tonejs`, right? and you want to test your component, correct? then you better mock 3rd party dependncies(like `tonejs` also is). and there will be no such an errors.

Comment: Hi mblos, I answered a very similar question a while ago. I think the answer is suitable for your question as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55272123/testing-a-library-that-uses-the-web-audio-api-with-mocha-chai/55473204#55473204 I hope it helps.