# Using AudioContext in unit tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, web-audio-api, midi

I am developing a JavaScript library (https://github.com/yvesgurcan/web-midi-player) to enable MIDI playback in a web application. The library relies on the Web Audio API to create a way to play these MIDI files (https://github.com/yvesgurcan/web-midi-player/blob/test/src/MidiPlayer.js#L50). However, I am having trouble creating meaningful unit tests with Jest (https://github.com/yvesgurcan/web-midi-player/blob/test/tests/midiPlayer.js) because these tests don't have access to the `window` object and more particularly to `window.AudioContext`. As a consequence, running my application code which relies on `AudioContext` throws errors related to the fact that this object does not exist and I can't actually test very much things in the library.

I've tried the following packages to solve my problem: `jsdom`, `jsdom-global`,  and also `web-audio-test-api` but none of these seem to inject `AudioContext` in the environment.

I am thinking that the solution here would be to stub/mock `AudioContext` but that does not sound like a good solution for solid unit tests.

What do you folks suggest to test the Web Audio API? Is stubbing the only viable solution here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it depends a bit on what you want to test. Since you're using Jest I imagine you're just interested in testing the correctness of your own code. In that case I would recommend to fully mock the Web Audio API. It's not part of your responsibility and you can assume it works the way it should. The only thing you have to test is if your code is making the expected calls.

Mocking globally available variables like the AudioContext constructor is always a bit tricky but you could allow an AudioContext to be passed into your `MidiPlayer` class as an optional argument. It would make testing a little easier and it would also allow users of your library to bring their own AudioContext.

I think of something like this:

```
class MidiPlayer {

    constructor({
        // ... the other options ...
        context = new AudioContext()
    }) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Inside a test you could then simply instantiate the `MidiPlayer` with a fake `AudioContext`.

```
const fakeAudioContext = {
    currentTime: 3,
    // ... and all the other things your code uses ...
};
const midiPlayer = new MidiPlayer({ context: fakeAudioContext });
```

I recently answered a [similar question related to Tone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55272123/testing-a-library-that-uses-the-web-audio-api-with-mocha-chai) which might be helpful. The basic idea is the same.

In case you want to test if your library works nicely with the Web Audio API in a browser I would recommend to use a test runner like [Karma](https://karma-runner.github.io). It executes the tests in a real browser and therefore can use all the browser APIs.

Comment: Thank you, Chris. I had seen the question on Tone.js before but didn't think of doing the same with `AudioContext`! I very much like the idea of giving both the option to use an existing `AudioContext` and give a stub to the `MidiPlayer` instance. It sounds like this would allow the user of the library to possibly extend functionalities that are not implemented in `web-midi-player` yet--such as controlling the volume of the audio. Am I correct to assume this? Are there possible downsides and other benefits to doing that? I greatly appreciate your expertise!

Comment: I think it's currently not really possible to use your `MidiPlayer` and append some effects to the signal chain since it currently connects directly to the `destination` of the `AudioContext`. https://github.com/yvesgurcan/web-midi-player/blob/test/src/MidiPlayer.js#L117 But you could optionally allow people to specify their own destination as well. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm not too knowledgeable with the Web Audio API yet but I've learnt a lot with this project. Letting people specify their own destination makes sense to me (as in how to achieve that in MidiPlayer) but I'm not sure I understand what appending effects to the signal chain would do because I'm not sure what effects and the signal chain are. I mean, I have ideas but I'm not sure :)

Comment: You could for example have an AudioContext somewhere in your application. Then you could create a GainNode as destination and instantiate a MidiPlayer like this: `new MidiPlayer({ context: myAudioContext, destination: myGainNode })`. It would then be possible to add an EQ before connecting the `myGainNode` to the `destination` of the AudioContext. `const filter = myAudioContext.createBiquadFilter(); myGainNode.connect(filter).connect(myAudioContext.destination);`